# how To Access OPENERP Methods From PHP?

Tags: php, xml-rpc, odoo

I need to Integrate open erp hr module with php website.For that I tried to use XML-RPC.
But i didnt get how to access its method.I need to use leave,timesheet, and payroll calculation from open erp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help.

http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/6_22_XML-RPC_web_services/index.html.

Comment: Is it any way to access and submit erp forms from php page using orm methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can access method in openerp the same way you access  other CRUD methods. 
It is not documented in openerp doc but it is possible to access methods defined in models.

Add below code to the openerp_models.php file from ttps://doc.openerp.com/6.1/developer/12_api/#xml-rpc-web-services. Download the php lib provided

```
<?php

public function call_openerp_func($model, $function, $ids) {

    $client = new xmlrpc_client($this->server . "object");

    $id_val = array();
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($ids as $id) {
        $id_val[$count++] = new xmlrpcval($id, "int");
    }



    $this->msg = new xmlrpcmsg('execute');
    $this->msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($this->database, "string"));
    $this->msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($this->id, "int"));
    $this->msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($this->password, "string"));
    $this->msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($model, "string"));
    $this->msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($function, "string"));
    $this->msg->addParam(new xmlrpcval($id_val, "array"));
    //////         
     */
    // Functions return values
    $this->res = &$this->client->send($this->msg);
    if ($this->res->faultCode()) {
        return 'Error: ' . $resp->faultString();
    } else {
        $res = $this->res->value();
        return $res;
    }
}
 ?>
```

And this how you call the above function

```
<?php
  // sample for calling function to validate invoice payment
   $validate_voucher_payment = $kengen_model->call_function_func('account.voucher', 
      'button_proforma_voucher', array(8));  
?>
```

Hope this solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use the web services using

Python ,Ruby ,PHP and Java Programming language

just need follow the below link

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/api_integration.html

I hope my answer may helpful for you :)